# Orchard CMS: Submenu refreshing entire page when clicked

Tags: orchardcms, submenu

I have a simple Forums module and a sub-menu (has five options) that belongs to the Forums module. I'm using the default Orchard theme (ThemeMachine) and I placed the sub-menu in the `AsideFirst` zone on a custom layer.

So, when I click on a "Forums" link in the main menu, I have the Forums sub-menu in the `AsideFirst` zone and all the forum threads in the `Content` zone.

The only problem is, when I click on one of the sub-menu options, I would like it to only fresh the `Content` zone with corresponding threads. Instead, now it is refreshing the entire area below the main menu and the two zones (AsideFirst and Content) get merged when any of the sub-menu options is clicked.

Is there a way I can modify the behavior without having to modify the source code?

**EDIT:** I get the sense that I might have to modify the source code after all. So, any insights in that regard will be very helpful, too.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal behavior. If you want to implement ajax behavior instead, you'll have to do it yourself, or use an extension such as this: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.IDeliverable.AjaxWidget/1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way or even the right way of implementing the behavior I described in my question but it achieved what I intended so I will just post it as an answer:

I converted all the sub-menu items to "custom links" and assigned a url for each of the areas (e.g., menu item "discussion" would have the url `~/forums/discussion` and so on).

As for the Forums layer, I added a rule that reads `url("~/forums*")`.

Lastly, I added the sub-menu (or the custom links I mentioned above) to one of the desired zones (LeftContent in my case) in the Forums layer. Now the sub-menu assigned to a zone in the Forums layer sticks and choosing any of the sub-menu items only refreshes the Content zone.